# how to install toolchain in Linux

Tags: linux, arm, qt-creator, linux-device-driver, toolchain

I wrote C++ code( show images) with qt creator in Linux. I want to put it into imx6Q to see my images on the display. I need some toolchain in Linux . Does anybody know that Gcc toolchain is enough for it? I am trying to find some information about it,i have never done it. Thanks for anyone's help.

Comment: You should ask this same question on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The imx6 series is based on the ARM architecture.
You could use one of the free Codesourcery "lite" cross-compiler toolchains for ARM available [**here**](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/).